# Counting string in cells?

Tags: field-calculator

How can I count strings? I would like to know how many words (strings) I have in each cell. So I know that somewhere is too many words. `Len()` function calculates individual string character (including spaces).

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: ArcGIS mostly but also QGIS

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom function for this purpose. In the Field Calculator, go to Function Editor and create a new function name it TextCount, as you can see below, and copy and paste the following code:

[image]

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def textCount(text_field, feature, parent):
    split_text = text_field.split()
    count_txt = len(split_text)
    return count_txt
```

Then from Custom functions select the function the you created and the field the you want to count and the count in a new field.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well described, Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use split to split into list, default split character is whitespaces:

```
a = "Can I somehow count strings? I would like to know how many words (strings) I have in every cell. So I know that somewere is too many words. Len function calculates individual string character (also spaces ). Tanks!"

a.split()
['Can', 'I', 'somehow', 'count', 'strings?', 'I', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'know', 'how', 'many', 'words', '(strings)', 'I', 'have', 'in', 'every', 'cell.', 'So', 'I', 'know', 'that', 'somewere', 'is', 'too', 'many', 'words.', 'Len', 'function', 'calculates', 'individual', 'string', 'character', '(also', 'spaces', ').', 'Tanks!']

print(len(a.split()))
38
```

Comment: Tanks! I got it.